# Parallel make doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, parallel-processing, makefile

I have building environment which is perfectly working on Windows XP.

But when I moved everything on my Windows 7 (x64) PC.

> make -j4

gives an message:

```
make: Do not specify -j or –jobs if sh.exe is not available.
make: Resetting make for single job mode
```

Using SHELL=CMD.EXE (also cmd.exe) doesn't help at all. Why?

Comment: do you have ComSpec set? For instance in windows 7 environment variables: ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Yes ComSpec is set as you mentioned...

Comment: Finally I've installed cygwin, but still make -j4 complains about missing sh.exe (despite that PATH variable is set to C:\cygwin\bin, where sh.exe is located, and also call sh.exe from command line is possible)... I don't get it at all.